# Xbonacci in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Xbonacci, the sum of the previous X numbers (instead of the previous 2 numbers) of the sequence becomes the next number in the sequence.

The method will take two arguments: the starting sequence with X number of elements and an integer N. The method will return the first N elements in the given sequence.

test case: xbonacci([1, 1], 5) => [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]

test case: xbonacci([1, 1, 1, 1], 8) => [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 13, 25]

here's my code:

```
def xbonacci(starting_sequence, number_of_xbonacci_numbers_to_return)
  result = starting_sequence

  until result.length == number_of_xbonacci_numbers_to_return
  result << result[-starting_sequence.length..-1].reduce(:+)
  end

result
end
```

My question is why the code wouldn't run properly unless I assign starting_sequence.length to a variable? More specifically, why can't the method be part of the range if such method returns an integer?

Comment: On a side note: maybe use shorter parameter names, it would make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array#dup` to create `result`. When you do `result = starting_sequence`, it will have the reference to same array as starting_sequence - which means, whenever you do `result << ..`, that *same* referred array is changed. When you check back `starting_sequence` again, it will give the same object, which is why `starting_sequence.length` changes in every iteration (increasing length by 1).

Creating a duplicate will prevent such issue.

```
def xbonacci(starting_sequence, number_of_xbonacci_numbers_to_return)
  result = starting_sequence.dup

  until result.length == number_of_xbonacci_numbers_to_return
    result << result[-starting_sequence.length..-1].reduce(:+)
  end

  result
end

xbonacci([1, 1, 1, 1], 8) #=> [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 13, 25]
```

> My question is why the code wouldn't run properly unless I assign starting_sequence.length to a variable?

Same reason. The other way is for you too assign the length to some variable so that it remains same in every iteration, when your `starting_sequence` is changing in every iteration.

Reference:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
#=> [1,2,3,4]
a.object_id
#=> 70262859031760
b = a
#=> [1,2,3,4]
b.object_id
#=> 70262859031760, same as that of arr
b << 5
a
#=> [1,2,3,4,5] # a changed too.
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know modifying b means I am also modifying a.

Comment: It *does not* mean that! You are *not* modifying `b`. You are *retrieving* the object *referenced* by `b` and modifying *that* object, which happens to be the *same* object that is also referenced by `a`. There is no "I modify this thing and that also modifies that other thing". There is *only one thing*. The only way to modify a local variable such as `b` is to assign to it, and that will *not* modify `a`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for correcting. :)  I edited the answer. Can you check if inference is correct now?

Comment: The comment was actually directed at the OP, not at you, but yes, the edit looks very good! Confusion between a variable and the object referenced by the variable is very common, and it helps being *extremely*, almost fanatically precise when talking about them.